# Spigot/Bukkit plugin - Detecting LOLCAT or Pirate locale language

Tags: java, locale, minecraft, bukkit

I tried joining my test server with LOLCAT or Pirate language. I had a PlayerJoinEvent which would log my locale in the console:

```
logger.info(event.getPlayer().spigot().getLocale());
```

However, it keeps logging en_US. I've also tried delaying it (if the server would maybe handle the PacketPlayInSettings after the PlayerJoinEvent) but that didn't work.

So, how would I detect a player having languages like LOLCAT or Pirate Speak?

Comment: I found this with a quick google https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/player-spigot-getlocale-always-returning-en_us.137468/ if you hadn't seen it already

Comment: I've seen that and it didn't solve anything.

Comment: Have you tried: https://bukkit.org/threads/get-a-players-minecraft-language.172468/

It's from 2013 but it should work.